# Trying to run this sql but I'm not sure if I'm doing it right

Tags: sql, db2

Hi I'm trying to run this sql but as I'm new to sql I'm getting errors and not sure if I'm doing it right.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
 V1.TREE_NAME AS "MSTR_ACCOUNT_ALL", 
 V1.TREE_NODE AS "REAL_ESTATE_EXP", 
 V1.REPORT_TYPE AS "C", 
 V1.ACCOUNT FROM PS_ACCT V1 
INNER JOIN PS_TRAN F1 ON F1.ACCOUNT = V1.ACCOUNT 
INNER JOIN PS_ACCT V2 ON V2.REPORT_TYPE = F1.REPORT_TYPE 
 where F1.ACCOUNT = V1.ACCOUNT
```

and I'm getting this error

DB2 Database Error: ERROR [42703] [IBM][DB2/AIX64 SQL0206N  "V1.PS_ACCT.ACCOUNT" is not valid in the context where it is used. SQLSTATE=42703

Comment: In the future you may want to include the exact error messages and codes, not just say "I'm getting errors".

Comment: And the errors are...?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with your query.

Firstly, you only need to refer to the table alias, not the full table name, e.g.:

```
SELECT DISTINCT V1.TREE_NAME = 'MSTR_ACCOUNT_ALL', 
     V1.TREE_NODE = 'REAL_ESTATE_EXP',
     V1.REPORT_TYPE = 'C'
     V1.ACCOUNT 
  FROM PS_ACCT V1
  INNER JOIN PS_TRAN F1 ON F1.ACCOUNT = V1.ACCOUNT
  INNER JOIN PS_ACCT V2 ON V2.REPORT_TYPE = F1.REPORT_TYPE
  where F1.ACCOUNT = V1.ACCOUNT
```

Secondly, your "where" clause merely restates the join condition between F1 and V1, so you can safely omit it (this wouldn't cause any error, though):

```
SELECT DISTINCT V1.TREE_NAME = 'MSTR_ACCOUNT_ALL', 
     V1.TREE_NODE = 'REAL_ESTATE_EXP',
     V1.REPORT_TYPE = 'C'
     V1.ACCOUNT 
  FROM PS_ACCT V1
  INNER JOIN PS_TRAN F1 ON F1.ACCOUNT = V1.ACCOUNT
  INNER JOIN PS_ACCT V2 ON V2.REPORT_TYPE = F1.REPORT_TYPE
```

Finally, your SELECT clause merely needs to list the columns you wish to report - the `=` is not valid syntax here:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
     V1.TREE_NAME,
     V1.TREE_NODE,
     V1.REPORT_TYPE,
     V1.ACCOUNT 
FROM PS_ACCT V1
INNER JOIN PS_TRAN F1 ON F1.ACCOUNT = V1.ACCOUNT
INNER JOIN PS_ACCT V2 ON V2.REPORT_TYPE = F1.REPORT_TYPE
```

Now, it's not clear from the very limited info you have supplied whether the `PS_ACCT` table/view has a column called `REPORT_TYPE`. If it doesn't, the query will fail as you have referred to the `V1` alias here.

Comment: Thanks for the help there is REPORT_TYPE column for PS_ACCT table. I'm still getting the error.  "DB2 Database Error: ERROR [42601] [IBM] [DB2/AIX64] SQL0104N  An unexpected token "V1" was found following "T.REPORT_TYPE AS "C"".  Expected tokens may include:  "INTO".  SQLSTATE=42601"

Comment: It would have helped to mention you're using DB2... But anyway, the error message is telling you what's wrong. If you want more help, please post the entire bit of code you're executing in your question.

Comment: This is whole code that I'm trying to run.                          SELECT DISTINCT V1.TREE_NAME AS 'MSTR_ACCOUNT_ALL', 
V1.TREE_NODE AS 'REAL_ESTATE_EXP', 
V1.REPORT_TYPE AS 'C' 
V1.ACCOUNT 
FROM PS_ACCT V1 
INNER JOIN PS_TRAN F1 ON F1.ACCOUNT = V1.ACCOUNT 
INNER JOIN PS_ACCT V2 ON V2.REPORT_TYPE = F1.REPORT_TYPE 
where F1.ACCOUNT = V1.ACCOUNT

Comment: I don't know DB2 very well but even I can see that's not valid SQL. e.g. I think you're missing a comma in `V1.REPORT_TYPE AS 'C' V1.ACCOUNT`. Also, I don't know if column aliases in DB2 are delimited by quotes (`'`).

Comment: I have changed this issues but still having an error. SELECT DISTINCT V1.TREE_NAME AS "MSTR_ACCOUNT_ALL", 
V1.TREE_NODE AS "REAL_ESTATE_EXP", 
V1.REPORT_TYPE AS "C", 
V1.ACCOUNT FROM PS_ACCT V1 
INNER JOIN PS_TRAN F1 ON F1.ACCOUNT = V1.ACCOUNT 
INNER JOIN PS_ACCT V2 ON V2.REPORT_TYPE = F1.REPORT_TYPE 
where F1.ACCOUNT = V1.ACCOUNT Eroor is "V1.PS_ACCT.ACCOUNT" is not valid in the context where it is used.  SQLSTATE=42703"